# Exception while trying to wrap List<String> with GenericEntity

Tags: java, json, jersey, jax-ws, marshalling

I have a Simple Rest Service Class like below:

```
@POST
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes( { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
@Path("getaudithistory")
public Response getAuditHistory(SearchBean searchBean)
{
    try
    {
       objMapper.getSerializationConfig().setSerializationInclusion(JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_DEFAULT);
       objMapper.getSerializationConfig().addMixInAnnotations(ClassA.class,
                                                               ClassAMixIn.class);
        for (ClassA bean : BeanHistory)
        {
            String str = objMapper.writeValueAsString(bean);
            finalList.add(str);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
       //TO-DO
    }
    GenericEntity<List<String>> list =
        new GenericEntity<List<String>>(finalList) {};
    return Response.ok(list).build();
}
```

When I run my service using Postman, I get below exception:

```
<Oct 13, 2016 5:10:36 AM PDT> <Warning> <Socket> <BEA-000449> <Closing socket as no data read from it on 10.176.181.179:57,451 during the configured idle timeout of 5 secs> 
<com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl> <WebApplicationImpl> <onException> <Internal server error> 
javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException: javax.xml.bind.MarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[com.sun.istack.SAXException2: unable to marshal type "java.lang.String" as an element because it is missing an @XmlRootElement annotation]
at com.sun.jersey.core.provider.jaxb.AbstractListElementProvider.writeTo(AbstractListElementProvider.java:164)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse.write(ContainerResponse.java:266)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:814)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:740)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:731)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:372)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:452)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:633)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:301)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:26)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
at oracle.adf.model.servlet.ADFBindingFilter.doFilter(ADFBindingFilter.java:229)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
at oracle.apps.fnd.applcore.common.ApplSessionFilter.doFilter(ApplSessionFilter.java:1205)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
at oracle.wsm.agent.handler.servlet.SecurityFilter.doFilter(SecurityFilter.java:401)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
at oracle.apps.appstrace.ui.servlet.AppsTraceRequestFilter.doFilter(AppsTraceRequestFilter.java:82)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
at oracle.wcps.client.PersonalizationFilter.doFilter(PersonalizationFilter.java:74)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
at oracle.webcenter.content.integration.servlets.ContentServletFilter.doFilter(ContentServletFilter.java:168)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
at oracle.adf.library.webapp.LibraryFilter.doFilter(LibraryFilter.java:166)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter$1.run(JpsAbsFilter.java:138)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at oracle.security.jps.util.JpsSubject.invokeAs(JpsSubject.java:427)
at oracle.security.jps.ee.util.JpsPlatformUtil.runJaasMode(JpsPlatformUtil.java:461)
at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.runJaasMode(JpsAbsFilter.java:121)
at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.doFilter(JpsAbsFilter.java:211)
at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsFilter.doFilter(JpsFilter.java:71)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
at oracle.dms.servlet.DMSServletFilter.doFilter(DMSServletFilter.java:163)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestEventsFilter.doFilter(RequestEventsFilter.java:27)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3730)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3696)
at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2273)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2179)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1490)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:256)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)
Caused by: javax.xml.bind.MarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[com.sun.istack.SAXException2: unable to marshal type "java.lang.String" as an element because it is missing an @XmlRootElement annotation]
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.write(MarshallerImpl.java:323)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.marshal(MarshallerImpl.java:177)
at com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONListElementProvider.writeList(JSONListElementProvider.java:108)
at com.sun.jersey.core.provider.jaxb.AbstractListElementProvider.writeTo(AbstractListElementProvider.java:162)
... 48 more
Caused by: com.sun.istack.SAXException2: unable to marshal type "java.lang.String" as an element because it is missing an @XmlRootElement annotation
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.reportError(XMLSerializer.java:252)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.LeafBeanInfoImpl.serializeRoot(LeafBeanInfoImpl.java:141)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsRoot(XMLSerializer.java:498)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.write(MarshallerImpl.java:320)
... 51 more
```

But If I try to pass only a single string through GenericEntity, I get perfect result.

```
GenericEntity<String> list =
        new GenericEntity<String>(str) {};
```

I am new to the concept of Jersey and Jackson, and have gone through almost everything I could find to resolve this but it didsn't solve the issue.
Any help in this regard will be appreciated.

Comment: can you add the configuration file ? I just wanted to see the how jersey is being initialized.

Comment: I deployed and ran the app again. The actual Exception coming is related to Marshaling. Edited details in the Question. Please have a look at it again

Comment: I'm afraid I can't help you more here as I dont use weblogic, but I can give you some pointers. First, you need to register jackson with weblogic if you are planning on using it. Second, b/c you don't have jackson, the jersey finds JaxB marshaller and tries to parse your response, but for this to work you will need a generic list wrapper with JaxB annotation as suggested in the error. The other thing I noticed you don't have to serailize your bean(ClassA bean) manually using object mapper. Once you have Jackson registered you can change the response to List<ClassA> instead of List<String>.